# I just saw two mentions in a comment

Tags: discussion

I just saw that Eric Lippert had a comment in which he had mentioned two people using `@`

How is that?

The syntax was correct. There was no space between @ and the name

When I try to do the same in SO, I get:

> "Only one user is allowed to be mentioned by @. The owner of the post will always be notified"

Note: In MSO, I don't get the error.

The link: [Should I seal all classes I know shouldn't ever be used as a base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164170/should-i-seal-all-classes-i-know-shouldnt-ever-be-used-as-a-base-class#comment-2110473)

Comment: Is there anything preventing it? There aren't two notifications, but I'm not sure it's impossible to write. You have a link?

Comment: So? I can type as many @ mentions as I like, but they *won't actually work*.

Comment: Yes, that worked but only *pinged me*. @Bart would not have been pinged.

Comment: I wasn't, so there you go.

Comment: Check out my edit

Comment: That is not at odds with what we told you

Comment: @MartijnPieters, see, I can mention in MSO, but when I try to do the same in SO, i get the stated error.

Comment: The error can be triggered here too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, how?

Comment: `@AmitJoki, @Bart` will trigger an error message.

Comment: @AmitJoki,@Bart

Comment: @MartijnPieters, did you see that? nothing happened

Comment: That probably only works if you're not addressing yourself @AmitJoki.

Comment: Guys, check out my edit. I've included the link

Comment: No space between the comma and the next @ doesn't trigger a notification.

Comment: Did you notice how old that comment was? That was back in 2010, and I doubt this was implemented at the time. Anyway, this really doesn't matter much.

Comment: Yeah @MartijnPieters, you are right

Comment: @AmitJoki and @­MartijnPieters it works

Comment: Is there a reason why only 1 is allowed? Faced this problem before when thanking multiple people on comments for improvements.

Comment: @pico.creator: because... [Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176040/163863).

Comment: @Matt Yeah well... Jeff doesn't work here anymore.  :-D  I bet his sphere of influence is still around...

Answer (score 8):

In some cases you are prevented from posting multiple @replies, for example when addressing the OP as well as another user, but in many cases nothing stops you from typing multiple @replies into a comment. However, they simply won't work (i.e. they won't notify multiple users) besides the first one.

And there are several other situations in which the formatting of what seems to be an @reply actually doesn't cause a notification as explained in ["How do comment @replies work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) over on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Actually, there are some blocks in place; using the OP name plus someone else for example.

Comment: So then that's "unless you're addressing the OP" @MartijnPieters?

Comment: Perhaps; not sure about all the ways to trigger it.

Comment: On [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23195863), there is a comment mentioning three people. One of them is the person who posted the answer, but the two others (one of them is me) aren't, so it's not as simple as that.

Answer (score 4):

The limit on how many you can @ping in a single comment wasn't always there. In the good old days, you could mention as many people as you wanted in comments.

Since it's a fairly old comment, that's probably why.

Comment: 'In the good old days' :)

Comment: why was it abolished?

Comment: I'd like to "up" the question of @thewaywewalk. It's very annoying sometimes to be forced for nothing to make two comments while you could just do one. I think I'm gonna make a new question.